# Verification on relation of some important spaces of a rectangular matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question has been asked earlier but I have some small observations related to this quesiton.
Sorry for bad English.

**Motivitation:**  Understand these spaces and its connections between them in the solution of $Ax=b$ where $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}.$

> (*) For any $A,B \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$, if
> $C(A)=C(B)$ does not always implies that $R(A)=R(B)$ and similarly converse is not always true

where $C(A),R(A),N(A) $ and $N(A^T)$ denote the column space, row space, null space and left null space of $A.$

Counter example for (*)

\begin{equation}A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}B=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation} both $A$ and $B$ have same column space (that is $\mathbb{R^2}$) but different row spaces ($xy-$ plane for $A$ and $xz-$ plane for $B$). Infact null spaces are different because of distinct row spaces but left null spaces are same since same column spaces.

**Observation(a):** If two matrices have same $C(A)=C(B) or R(A)=R(B)$ then other three are not hold like in above case but if they have same $C(A)=C(B) and N(A)=N(B)$ or $R(A)=R(B) and N(A^T)=N(B^T)$ then the other two are also same.

**(b)** If matrices $A$ and $B$ are square and invertible all four spaces are equal for both the matrices.

I need verification, any hints/solutions is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.